# Invalid value provided to SecureStore. Values must be strings; consider JSON-encoding your values if they are serializable

Tags: react-native, expo

Try to store value to expo SecureStore but got this error

```
Invalid value provided to SecureStore. Values must be strings; consider JSON-encoding your values if they are serializable.
- node_modules\expo-secure-store\build\SecureStore.js:25:14 in setItemAsync$
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:170:17 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:23 in doResolve
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:12 in Promise
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:169:27 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:216:8 in <unknown>
- node_modules\expo-secure-store\build\SecureStore.js:22:7 in setItemAsync
* src\context\AuthContext.js:32:37 in _callee$
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
- ... 13 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Here is the code that I am trying...

```
await SecureStore.setItemAsync('email',response.data.email);
```

Comment: Can you add screenshot of response.data.email?

Comment: can you provide a more details, like is this a warning or error? I did faced an issue like this but depending on the type  the solution changes.

Answer (score 3):

The conversion must be done before sending the friend variable, even though JSON (), it follows how it would look

**await SecureStore.setItemAsync('email',JSON.stringify(response.data.email));**